# Markov Chain Expected Time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

[image]

I am studying Markov Chain Expected time. I came across this formula. However, it wasn't state explicitly when would the formula apply.

In the following photo, do you guys think the formula above also applied on markov chain below?

I want to calculate the expected time to return back to state 0 if started from state 0.

[image]

Here is the result of apply the formula to my problem above.  Wolfram told me no solution exists.

[image]

Comment: what formula? All I see is a sideways textbook page. I think there's a formula on there somewhere. You could have at least wrote out the one you mean, either in tex or on that paper you scanned.

Comment: If you're referring to some kind of recursion equation for the mean hitting time of each state, then yes, it's applicable for your situation.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. I was using my phone and I didn't log into computer.

Comment: The problem is that, I have wrote out the system of equations using the formula, wolfram alpha told me that no solution exist.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland , thanks for your reply. Do you know why the formula gives me wrong answer?

Comment: The scan from your textbook talks about "time until absorption", but the hand drawn problem is about "time until return to the starting point". These are different problems, and the equation for the absorption problem doesn't work in the "starting point" problem.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland , I am wondering what would be your formula for your link? I have worked it out using the stationary probability equation. And the expected time to return is simply 1/s0

Comment: @randy I removed the link when I realized that it solves a third, unrelated, problem. You have already discovered the best solution; the one that uses the stationary distribution. The answer is $1/\pi_0=8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct set of equations for your problem. We define $T=\inf(t\geq 1: X_t=0)$ and define $S_j=\mathbb{E}_j(T).$ Then first step analysis gives 
\begin{eqnarray*}
S_0&=&1+S_1\\
S_1&=&1+(1/3) 0+ (2/3)S_2\\
S_2&=&1+(2/3)S_1+(1/3)S_3\\
S_3&=&1+S_2
\end{eqnarray*}

Notice that you should replace $S_0$ in your second equation with $0$ (zero).

Comment: Byron, Thanks for your answer. I agree this is the correct solution. Is it possible to explain why i need to replace S0 with 0? Am I treat it as a absorbing state?

Comment: @randy If you start at state 1, then jump to the left, how many *additional* steps do you need to reach your goal? Answer: zero.